# PHP pathing include issue

Tags: php, include-path

I am having the following problem:

```
Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Mail_Mime/mime.php' for
inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/myUserName/public_html/ssp/php/send-email-form.php on line 5
```

At the top of my php page I have the following:

```
include_once('Mail.php');
include_once('Mail_Mime/mime.php');
```

Update: Cpanel says my php extensions are located at /home/cloudbit/php I can see mime.php and mail.php in /home/USERNAME/php/mail/

Any idea how I basically tell it to use that path mentioned in the error? New to this.

Thanks 
Mark

Comment: This path either needs to be absolute or relative to the scripts directory.

Comment: Is there a Mail_Mime folder in either `.`, `/usr/lib/php`, or `/usr/local/lib/php`?

Comment: Use which path mentioned in the error? 'Mail_Mime/mime.php' is the relative path that it couldn't find. It tried `./Mail_Mime/mime.php`, `/usr/lib/php/Mail_Mime/mime.php`, and `/usr/local/lib/php/Mail_Mime/mime.php` but found no match.

Comment: where's your files `Mail.php` and `Mail_Mime/mime.php` located?

Comment: Hiya, Cpanel says my php extensions are located at /home/cloudbit/php I can see mime.php and mail.php in /home/cloudbit/php/mail/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hiya, Cpanel says my php extensions are located at /home/cloudbit/php I can see mime.php and mail.php in /home/cloudbit/php/mail/ – Mark H

Then your include should look as follows:

```
include_once('mail/mail.php');
include_once('mail/mime.php');
```

Comment: Hi im still getting a error for both mail and mime: Warning: include_once(mail/mail.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/cloudbit/public_html/ssp/php/send-email-form.php on line 4

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/mail/mail.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/cloudbit/public_html/ssp/php/send-email-form.php on line 4

Comment: You first said, that your PHP-files reside inside `/home/cloudbit/php/`, which isn't true, as one can see from your error-messages: `/home/cloudbit/public_html/ssp/php`. I don't know where your mail-classes are, as you didn't give any feasible information. You really need to understand the basics (like knowing your OS) before starting programming… (You didn't read the comments on your question, did you? The answer was given already: "path either needs to be absolute or relative to the scripts directory". -1 now for thinking about what was said…)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this exact same problem at my hosting provider by adding the include path at runtime.   My PHP files were in `~/www/` , but the PEAR modules were in `~/php/` .

See this link:  [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/set_include_path)

Hope this helps someone out there.